# exec for a sh function

Tags: bash, function, sh, exec

A commonly-used program here is often invoked at the ends of the shell scripts and we use `exec` to skip the implicit `fork` and prevent `sh`-process from waiting for the command to finish:

```sh
...
exec mycommand
# Unreached
```

Lately, however, we implemented a wrapper function around the command in order to have some common arguments inside it:

```sh
...
function mycommand () {
    command mycommand -foo -bar "$@"
}
```

The code calling `exec mycommand` continues to call the actual program instead of calling into the function, so we had to replace it with just `mycommand`.

But now the calling shell waits for `mycommand` to finish...

Changing the function to *always* `exec mycommand` is not acceptable, because it is not always the last command in the script. Often, but not always.

How'd we get both: a wrapping function *and* the ability to `exec` the program without forking, when appropriate? Creating a separate function (`exec_mycommand`) seems ugly...

Answer (score 1):

You could put exec after the function instead on in front of it.

```
function mycommand () {
    if [ "$1" = exec ]; then
        shift
        exec command mycommand -foo -bar "$@"
    else
        command mycommand -foo -bar "$@"
    fi
}
```

Then in the main body put either `mycommand exec` or `mycommand`.